# Can't log in as user. SSD drive from broken macbook inserted into a new macbook.

Tags: ssd, migration

Pre-story:
An older 2009 Macbook Pro 13"’s logic board has broken and I’ve got a working 2010 Macbook Pro 13".

Old Macbook was upgraded with SSD drive that was used as a system drive and `home` folder was configured to point at the HDD that was connected via SuperDrive’s SATA.

I have replaced “new” Macbook’s HDD with old Macbook’s SSD. It seems to boot fine, but I can’t login into user’s account and getting the following error:

> logging in to the account failed because an error occurred

The reason seems to be [according to google], that user’s home folder can’t be found (which makes sense). Since the laptop I’ve got is given to me for temporarily use I don’t want to replace SuperDrive on the “new” Macbook with the old HDD.

How can I reset home folder to point at new location (that would be on SSD) without logging in?